# Contextual filters in views rest export for decoupled website

Tags: views, javascript, 8

I'm running a Drupal 8.3.2 site and currently explore the concepts of using Restful webservices, jsonapi and React.js in a progessively decoupled project.

I installed the jsonapi module and fetched some data using axios and a small react.js app that gets mounted in a custom drupal-block on the front-page of my site. This all works and making use of jsonapi's sparse fieldsets, includes, filters etc. works well. However, the site uses lots of Drupal views that work with contextual filters and extracting the data I want to show is easy to do with views. I could of course use the power of the jsonapi and just "duplicate" the view with an axios GET request. However, since the view already provides all the content/filters I want, making use of the view via Rest-export would be nice.

My views use contextual filters. Some of them I provide via a `hook_views_pre_view()` adding values from the user's `private_tempstore` Session object to the view's `$args` array, some are just the user Id of the currently logged in user - set via the view's UI. When using a Restexport of this view and displaying the data inside the react app on the site's front page (using `axios.get(http://localhost/website/rest/exampleview)` in React.js , it works well even without specifying the contextual filter values in the GET Url.

Is this approach safe as long as the React app is running on the same server inside the same browser? I guess it's not fully clear to me if this always works and what exactly happens in the background (i.e. in my example I am the only logged in user, but what happens when a second user is also logged in and sends a GET request using the same endpoint/rest-path?)